# Вставка изображения из буфера памяти в программу WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть десктопное приложение в котором реализован небольшой чат с возможностью прикрепления файлов. Вопрос таков, есть ли какие либо nuget пакеты которые бы позволили вставлять скриншоты в программу сочетанием клавиш ctrl+v для дальнейшей загрузки и отправки? И если таких не существует, то кто может рассказать от и до как такое можно реализовать? От примеров тоже не откажусь) Буду очень благодарен)

Comment: [Clipboard Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за ссылку) Почитаю что это такое)

Comment: Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25751020/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP можете оставить данную ссылку как ответ, она мне помогла, там все описано как надо. Отмечу как правильный ответ. Спасибо)

Comment: Напишите ответ самостоятельно, я бы оформил сразу, если бы было время и желание